# How to push data from one Common Data Service to another CDS triggered by a status change of a record?

Tags: dynamics-365, power-automate, common-data-service

All environments are in the same tenant, same Azure Active Directory.

Need to push data from one environment's (Line of Business) Common Data Service to another environment's Common Data Service (Central Enterprise CDS) where reporting is running from.

I've looked into using OData Dataflows, however this seems like more of a manually triggered option.

Comment: any followup questions?

Answer (score 1):

OData dataflows is meant for and designed to support migration and synchronization of large datasets in Common Data Service during such scenarios:

> A one-time cross-environment or cross-tenant migration is needed (for
> example, geo-migration).
>
> A developer needs to update an app that is being used in production.
> Test data is needed in their development environment to easily build
> out changes.

Reference: [Migrate data between Common Data Service environments using the dataflows OData connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/cds-odata-dataflows-migration)

For continuous data synchronization, [use the CDS connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/connection-cds#initiate-a-flow-from-common-data-service) in Power Automate and  attribute filters for source CDS record updates to target CDS entities.

[image]